# OpenAndActivateDocument for Revit 2011

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

Is there any way to open and activate a document in the Revit API 2011 just like the 2012 API with the OpenAndActivateDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.
The best hack you can do is one of these two things:

After opening using the traditional open method:
 - Use the UIDocument.ShowElements() routine to try to show a known element
 - force the graphics to be rendered by exporting a JPEG of a view (or printing)

All in all, it's not ideal - but that's what you have to work with in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and activate a Revit document, including both local document or cloud document using following method:

```
OpenAndActivateDocument Method (String)
```

where string is a full path to a revit file to be opened. The file can be either a Revit project, template, or family document. This method will work for Revit 2019 too.